# Vertx Service Proxy class not calling another method till another is completed

Tags: reactive-programming, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I have implemented service proxy class over the event bus, which has 2 methods (**collect & cancel**) **collect** method is taking 4 to 5 minutes to complete because it is over the network and collecting the data from the device.

But in between collecting the data if I am calling the **cancel** on the service proxy which will usually stop the collecting the data from the device is **not calling**.

The **cancel method** is waiting to complete the **collect method** and then request is coming into **cancel**.

I have **2 verticles** one for handling **HTTP requests** and second is for **collecting the data**,.

CollcetionServiceProxy class is exposed over event bus through CollectionVerticle which **I am deploying as a worker verticle**.

At the time of deployment, If I deploy **2 instances of CollectionVerticle**   **It works fine But** I don't want to do that.

How Can I resolve this issue with Single Verticle Instance of collection.

Comment: can you share the code of how you are calling these two methods?

Comment: Is your collection built blocking? Show some code!

Answer (score 0):

A approach you could take is to send the request over the EventBus to start collection. The response would be just an acknowledgement. Your collector verticles would send data to a temp address the original request had stated. In each iteration of the loop the collector checks an “isCanceled” flag for the request which could be set by the other action. 
Bonus track: wrap that into a flowable, so your business logic doesn’t need to know the eventbus Mechanic below it. 
I [described something like that](https://wissel.net/blog/2019/12/a-streaming-pattern-for-the-vert.x-eventbus.html) recently.

To be very clear. When your code looks like this:

```
WorkerExecutor executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("my-worker-pool");
executor.executeBlocking(promise -> { 
// Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
 String result = someAPI.blockingMethod("hello");
 promise.complete(result); },
 res -> { System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result());
});
```

**NOTHING** will interrupt your `someAPI.blockingMethod("hello");` call. The only thing you could do is to fail the promise at the end.

However, and I presume that's the case here, you wrote the `someAPI` (to some extend). then you could do something like this:

```
public class CollectorVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    private final ConcurrentMap <long, AtomicBoolean> cancelTracker = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
...
```

Inside your execution:

```
final long key = Date.getTime(); // We use a Milisecond as key
executor.executeBlocking(promise -> { 
// Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
someAPI.fixedblockingMethod(result, cancelTracker, key, "hello");
 promise.complete(result.toString());
 },
 res -> {
    if res.succeeded() {
       System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result());
    } else {
      // Do whatever - check for error etc
    }
    cancelTracker.remove(key);
});

}
```

Then in your method along these lines:

```
fixedblockingMethod(StringBuilder b, Map cancelTracker, long key, String whatever) {

  for (int i =0; i < eternity; i++) {
      if (!cancelTracker.get(key).get() {
        break;
      }
      b.append(getNextItemFromInterface();
  }
}
```

That should do the trick.
I would still send individual items over the eventbus instead of collecting on the blocking method

Comment: In my CollectionVerticle, I am running a blocking code in WorkerExecuter, Which I think doesn't run on the same event loop or it used different thread pool.

Comment: like : WorkerExecutor executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("my-worker-pool");
executor.executeBlocking(promise -> {
  // Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
  String result = someAPI.blockingMethod("hello");
  promise.complete(result);
}, res -> {
  System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result());
});

Comment: you need to change `someAPI.blockingMethod` to check for abortion. See my extended answer above

Comment: My Concern is I want to put all same type of methods in one service proxy class

Comment: By Same class, I can call the method on one queue instead of creating different queues

Comment: You might want to step back and look at the problem to solve, rather than insisting on the solution approach you are stuck with. Elaborate more on “one queue”. What do you mean with that?

Comment: one queue means, I am exposing service proxy class on the event bus on one address like "collection-event", which will do collection related stuff and that service Proxy class have collect and cancel method.

Comment: one queue means, I am exposing service proxy class on the event bus on one address like "collection-event", which will do collection related stuff and that service Proxy class have collect and cancel method.

Comment: That’s UP - how external services see the collection-event. The internal implementation could be different

Answer (score 0):

base on your code sample

```
WorkerExecutor executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("my-worker-pool"); 
  executor.executeBlocking(promise -> { // Call some blocking API that takes significant amount of time to return String result = 
  someAPI.blockingMethod("hello"); 
  promise.complete(result); 
}, res -> { 
  System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result()); 
});
```

you are looking to stop blocking code, by the name of it, blocking code cannot be stoped till it end

so one approach will be to make this blocking code check periodically if it should be canceled

one implementation will be to make your blocking code return a completable future, and cancel it on event